# Qual é a relação entre "analogia" e o relógio, botão e sinal analógicos?

Tags: significado

Sempre tive uma noção de que algo analógico é algo contrário de digital, algo mecânico (como no caso do relógio). Porém fui ver no dicionário o significado de analógico e não encontro alguma relação com esses objetos.

[Analógico](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/anal%C3%B3gico):

> 1. Relativo à analogia.
> 2. Que tem ou se baseia na analogia.

Não ajudou nada, mas beleza...

[Analogia](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/analogia):

> 1. Relação de semelhança entre objetos diferentes.
> 2. Investigação da causa das semelhanças.
> 3. Razão da formação das palavras.

Pelo menos no caso dos [botões analógicos](http://mlb-s1-p.mlstatic.com/par-boto-analogico-controle-playstation-3-ps3-play-3-14747-MLB3605131235_122012-O.jpg), a primeira definição talvez faria sentido, pois são dois botões iguais, embora com funções diferentes.

Porém os botões analógicos, assim como tudo que é chamado de "analógico", em inglês são "analog" ("análogos"), ao invés de "analogical" ("analógico").

[Análogo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/an%C3%A1logo):

> adjetivo
>
> 1. Que tem analogia. = <sub><sup>EQUIVALENTE, IDÊNTICO, SEMELHANTE</sup></sub> ≠ <sub><sup>DIFERENTE, DISTINTO, DIVERSO</sup></sub>
> 2. Que provém de fatos idênticos.
>
> substantivo masculino
>
> 3. Coisa análoga.

Então minha pergunta é: por que essas coisas são classificadas como analógicas (ou análogas) e que relação tem a definição da palavra com o tipo dos mesmos?

Comment: Muito interessante a sua dúvida.

Comment: Não sei se sabiam da existência dos chamados *computadores analógicos*. Reformulei a resposta em torno deles, porque me parecem que esta distinção entre analógico e digital nasceu precisamente da distinção entre computadores analógicos e digitais.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[***Analogia***](http://www.aulete.com.br/analogia) é uma semelhança ou paralelismo entre duas coisas diferentes. Duas coisas são [***análogas***](http://www.aulete.com.br/an%C3%A1logo) (*analogous* em inglês) se são semelhantes nalgum aspeto. E no que aqui nos interessa, um processo ou método [***analógico***](http://www.aulete.com.br/anal%C3%B3gico) (*analog* ou *analogue* em inglês) baseia-se numa analogia entre fenómenos físicos. A oposição entre *analógico* e *digital* parece ter nascido na computação. Para clarificar esta distinção, vou tentar explicar o que  é um [*computador analógico*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computador_anal%C3%B3gico) a partir de um exemplo da [Wikipedia inglesa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer#Electronic_analog_computers). Os computadores analógicos são normalmente concebidos para um fim específico. Eis aqui um exemplo de um [computador analógico eletrónico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer#Electronic_analog_computers) concebido para prever o comportamento de molas e amortecedores:

> «A semelhança entre componentes mecânicos lineares, como molas e amortecedores de fluidos viscosos (*dashpots*), e componentes elétricos, como [capacitores (ptBR) ou condensadores (ptPT)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor), [indutores](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indutor) e [resistores](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor) é extraordinária em termos matemáticos.» (Minha tradução.)
>
> Assim é possível simular o funcionamento de amortecedores através de um sistema elétrico.
>
> «Todas as medições podem ser feitas diretamente com um [osciloscópio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscilosc%C3%B3pio). No circuito, a rigidez (simulada) da mola, por exemplo, pode ser alterada ajustando os parâmetros do capacitor (condensador). **O sistema elétrico é uma analogia do sistema físico**, daí o seu nome, mas é mais barato de construir, geralmente mais seguro, e tipicamente mais fácil de modificar.» (Minha tradução, ênfase minha.)

Portanto um computador analógico representa grandezas do problema que está a estudar (amortecedores, por exemplo) através de grandezas de fenómenos físicos (elétricos, por exemplo), explorando a analogia entre as duas grandezas. Em contraste, um computador digital representa as grandezas do problema a estudar através de dígitos, ou algarismos. Recorre portanto à simbologia e não à analogia.

As grandezas físicas são variáveis contínuas (no sentido matemático), isto é, podem ter variações infinitesimais, enquanto os dígitos são discretos. E daqui parecem ter nascido mais dois significados das palavras *analógico* e *digital*. Veja-se no [*analógico* no Aulete:](http://www.aulete.com.br/digital)

> **4.** Inf. Que mede uma grandeza ou apresenta valores de modo contínuo ou linear: *relógio com mostrador analógico* [Cf., nesta acp., *digital*.]

Esta definição corresponde à de [*analog* no inglês](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analog) e foi provavelmente influenciada por ela. Por sua vez, [*digital* no Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/digital) significa:

> **4.** Inf. Que tem o intervalo entre dois valores dividido num número finito de divisões. [Cf. nesta acp.: *analógico.*]

Podemos agora compreender facilmente a razão de ser dos nomes *botão, sinal e relógio analógicos*.

Um exemplo de [***botão analógico***](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/111863/what-is-an-analog-face-button) numa consola de jogos é um botão em que com quanto mais força se pressiona mais depressa o carro anda. Existe uma analogia entre a pressão no botão e a velocidade do carro. Neste contexto, um botão "digital" seria por exemplo um que pudesse apenas estar ligado ou desligado.

O [***sinal analógico***](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinal_anal%C3%B3gico), (mais bem explicado no [***analog signal*** da Wikipedia inglesa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_signal)) explora também a analogia entre duas forças físicas. Por exemplo, na transmissão de som a pressão das ondas sonoras num diafragma refletem-se de forma contínua na voltagem instantânea do sinal. Enquanto num sinal digital, essa pressão é indicada por uma série de zeros e uns. Portanto o sinal analógico é análogo ao som, enquanto o sinal digital é um representação simbólica do som.

Creio que os ***relógios analógicos*** só receberam esse nome para se distinguirem dos ***relógios digitais***. Antes eram simplesmente relógios. A [wikipédia inglesa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_watch) concorda, e chama a «*relógio eletrónico*» [*retrónimo*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retr%C3%B3nimo). Novamente neste caso o relógio analógico representa a passagem do tempo através de um fenómeno físico análogo, o movimento dos ponteiros; enquanto o relógio digital representa a passagem do tempo simbolicamente através de dígitos.

É claro que a tecnologia e a engenhosidade dos fabricantes avança, força a língua e gera celeumas. Existem agora relógios eletrónicos com imagens de ponteiros (ver comentário do ANeves). O mostrador é analógico, mas por baixo do mostrador há um processador digital (baseado no processamento de algarismos, [significado 3 do Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/anal%C3%B3gico)), o que justificaria classificar o relógio como digital.

Estes exemplos de processos analógicos têm em comum a existência de uma analogia entre dois fenómenos físicos: velocidade análoga à pressão no botão; voltagem análoga à pressão no diafragma; e movimento do ponteiro análogo ao movimento metafórico do tempo. Em oposição, nos processos [***digitais***](http://www.aulete.com.br/digital) o fenómeno é representado simbolicamente por [***dígitos***](http://www.aulete.com.br/d%C3%ADgito), algarismos: o significado dos dígitos corresponde ao fenómeno; mas não existe nenhuma analogia entre os dígitos enquanto objetos (tinta no papel, luz numa tela, ou mesmo a forma do dígito) e a passagem do tempo ou intensidade do som. E não acaba aqui. Por exemplo uma máquina fotográfica digital representa simbolicamente uma imagem através de zeros e uns, enquanto uma máquina tradicional representa a imagem por analogia numa película.

Comment: Acho que vais numa boa direção, mas não estou *nada* convencido pelos teus argumentos referentes aos relógios. A onomatopeia dos relógios é um tic-toc discreto, nada contínuo. E um relógio digital tipicamente tem números que mudam discretamente, mas pode perfeitamente ter ponteiros de movimento fluido. Podemos se calhar tentar argumentar que historicamente os relógios digitais tinham números (representação abstrata de um valor abstrato), e os analógicos tinham ponteiros (representação concreta de um valor abstrato)?

Comment: @ANeves Os movimentos dos ponteiros podem ser ou não estritamente contínuos, mas as posições dos ponteiros ficam num contínuo. Em inglês "analog clock" parece ser uma frase [bastante nova](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=analog+clock%2Canalogue+clock&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canalog%20clock%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canalogue%20clock%3B%2Cc0), mas não estou a conseguir encontrar se "analog clock" começou a ser usado com ideia em analogia ou continuidade. Alguém sabe se "relógio analógico" tem a mesma idade?

Comment: @DanGetz [Analog/analogue display](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=analog+display%2Canalogue+display&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canalog%20display%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canalogue%20display%3B%2Cc0) começou a ser usado uma duas décadas antes de *analog clock*. Estou convencido que a terminologia portuguesa foi muito influenciada pela inglesa.

Comment: @ANeves Editei a resposta. Tu para veres as horas olhas para os ponteiros, não contas os tiques e os taques. Agora há também aqueles relógios, relativamente antigos, acho, em que as horas e minutos são mostrados por cartões com números que vão mudando (estádios, estações). Imagino que os primeiros eram mecânicos. Será que alguma vez lhes chamaram digitais?